# How to add next-translate to next.config

Tags: next.js

I am trying to implement more languages in my Next project and I am confused by the documentation of library next-translate.

In documentation is next.config.ts:

```
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')
module.exports = nextTranslate()
```

But I have next.config in Next project version >12 like this (it is default):

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This version of next.config not working for me - there are same code issues:

```
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

module.exports = nextTranslate({
  webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
    return config;
  }
})
```

In next.config I have one module.export already, so how can I add a second module.export, or how can I implement next-translate to the next.config? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your custom `nextConfig` as a parameter to `nextTranslate()` .

Use this code:

```js
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

module.exports = nextTranslate({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, with small changes, it works

Comment: whenever you faced problems related to `next.config.js ` , try to read new package's source code. you can find useful information about functions there.